# Phase of BCS wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

Can anyone explain to me why the phase of the BCS wavefunction

$|\Psi_\text{BCS}\rangle=\prod_\mathbf{k}(|u_\mathbf{k}|+|v_\mathbf{k}|e^{i\theta_\mathbf{k}}
\hat{c}_{\mathbf{k}\uparrow}^\dagger\hat{c}_{-\mathbf{k}\downarrow}^\dagger)|0\rangle$

can be taken to be independent of $\mathbf{k}$, i.e. we can write

$|\Psi_\text{BCS}\rangle=\prod_\mathbf{k}(|u_\mathbf{k}|+|v_\mathbf{k}|e^{i\theta}
\hat{c}_{\mathbf{k}\uparrow}^\dagger\hat{c}_{-\mathbf{k}\downarrow}^\dagger)|0\rangle$

I suspect it may be a result of using Cooper's simplified interaction of the form $V_{\mathbf{k}\mathbf{k}'}=-V$, so that the gap parameter $\Delta_\mathbf{k}$ is independent of $\mathbf{k}$, but am not entirely sure.